# How to use $push/$addToSet mongodb update modifiers on python dicts

Tags: python, mongodb

Mongodb updates provide the `$push` modifier to append to an array. My problem is that i want this to happen on a dict e.g

If my record looks like this initially:

```
{"collaborations":{'id1':{'role':'dev','scope':'dev'}}}
```

I want to add another item("id2" below) to the "collaborations" field dict to look something like this:

```
{"collaborations":{'id1':{'role':'dev','scope':'dev'},'id2':{'role':'qa','scope':'qa'}}}
```

I am trying with `$push`:

```
my_record.update({match_criteria},{$push,{"collaborations":{'id2':{'role':'qa','scope':'qa'}}}})
```

and also with `$addToSet`:

```
my_record.update({match_criteria},{$,{"collaborations":{'id2':{'role':'qa','scope':'qa'}}}})
```

With both of these, mongodb throws as error "Cannot apply `$addToSet`(`$push`) modifier to non-array".

How can this be done for dict types? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `$addToSet` and `$push` modifiers work with arrays.

To update sub-document (that is what you need here) just use `$set` modifier with dot notation to access sub-document (`field.subfield`):

```
my_record.update({
    match_criteria
}, {
    '$set': {
        'collaborators.id2': {
            // new document fields here
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: please mark as answered to help others when googling for this issue :)